# How to add a object to a sorted set that's within a hashmap of objects

Tags: java, object, collections, hashmap, sortedset

I'm trying to add a passenger object into a sorted set. This sorted set is in a cruise object. All of the cruise objects are within a hashMap. I'm kinda new to collections so I'm having trouble. This is my attempt to do what I'm doing.

```
HashMap<String, Cruise> cruiseMap = new HashMap<String, Cruise>();
SortedSet<Passenger> passengerSet = new TreeSet<Passenger>();
Queue<Passenger> waitingList = new LinkedList<Passenger>();

Cruise cruise = new Cruise("1", passengerSet, waitingList, false);

cruiseMap.put("1", cruise);
Passenger passenger = new Passenger("Smith", "J");
cruiseMap.get("1").getPassengerSet().add(passenger);
```

The passenger's parameters are strings that are last name then their first initial. The cruise's parameters are as a string the date, the sortedSet passengers, there's a queue for waiting list and a boolean variable to determine if the ship has departed. I keep getting tons of errors when I run this code. Thanks in advance for the help.

Here are the errors I'm recieving.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: edu.ilstu.Passenger cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
at java.util.TreeMap.compare(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TreeMap.put(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TreeSet.add(Unknown Source)
at edu.ilstu.Driver.main(Driver.java:48)
```

**Passenger Class**

```
public class Passenger {
    private String lastName = "";
    private String firstName = "";

    public Passenger()
    {
        lastName = "no last name yet";
        firstName = "no first name yet";
    }
    public Passenger(String lastName, String firstName)
    {
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    /**
     * @return the lastName
     */
    public String getLastName()
    {
        return lastName;
    }
    /**
     * @param lastName the lastName to set
     */
    public void setLastName(String lastName)
    {
    this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    /**
     * @return the firstName
     */
    public String getFirstName()
    {
        return firstName;
    }
    /**
     * @param firstName the firstName to set
     */
    public void setFirstName(String firstName)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
     */
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return lastName + " " + firstName;
    }
}
```

**Cruise Class**

```
public class Cruise
    {
    private String day = "";
    private  SortedSet<Passenger> passengerSet = new TreeSet<Passenger>();
    private Queue<Passenger> waitingList = new LinkedList<Passenger>();
    private boolean hasDeparted = false;

    public Cruise()
    {
        day = "no day yet";
        passengerSet = null;
        waitingList = null;
        hasDeparted = false;
    }

    public Cruise(String day, SortedSet<Passenger> passengerSet,     Queue<Passenger> waitingList, boolean hasDeparted)
    {
        this.day = day;
        this.passengerSet = passengerSet;
        this.waitingList = waitingList;
        this.hasDeparted = hasDeparted;
    }

    /**
     * @return the day
     */
    public String getDay()
    {
        return day;
    }

    /**
     * @param day the day to set
     */
    public void setDay(String day)
    {
        this.day = day;
    }

    /**
     * @return the passengerSet
     */
    public SortedSet<Passenger> getPassengerSet()
    {
        return passengerSet;
    }

    /**
     * @param passengerSet the passengerSet to set
     */
    public void setPassengerSet(SortedSet<Passenger> passengerSet)
    {
        this.passengerSet = passengerSet;
    }

    /**
     * @return the waitingList
     */
    public Queue<Passenger> getWaitingList()
    {
        return waitingList;
    }

    /**
     * @param waitingList the waitingList to set
     */
    public void setWaitingList(Queue<Passenger> waitingList)
    {
        this.waitingList = waitingList;
    }

    /**
     * @return the hasDeparted
     */
    public boolean isHasDeparted()
    {
        return hasDeparted;
    }

    /**
     * @param hasDeparted the hasDeparted to set
     */
    public void setHasDeparted(boolean hasDeparted)
    {
        this.hasDeparted = hasDeparted;
    }

}
```

Comment: Add the actual errors to your question, please.

Comment: Also add the Cruise and Passenger class please.

Comment: The information has been added.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.programcreek.com/2009/02/implement-comparable-for-a-treeset/)?

Comment: That link helped me figure it out! Thanks. I needed to implement Comparable in the passenger class. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because your `passengerSet` is `TreeSet` (`SortedSet`), which means it will sort itself after each adding, because `TreeSet` is ordered set and has certain sequence unlike usual `HashMap`. Every `SortedMap` must know how to sort elements it contains. This can be done two ways:

1. You can implement your class from `Comparable<T>` interface.
2. You can add custom `Comparator<T>` to your `SortedMap`.

So, you have three ways to fix it (may be more, but three of them - are obvious):

1. Get rid of `SortedMap`, let's say replace your `SortedMap` to `Map` and replace `TreeMap` to `HashMap` in your code.
2. Add custom comparator to your `passengerSet`

   ```
   HashMap<String, Cruise> cruiseMap = new HashMap<String, Cruise>();
   SortedSet<Passenger> passengerSet = new TreeSet<Passenger>(new Comparator<Passenger>() {

       @Override
       public int compare(Passenger lhs, Passenger rhs) {
           return lhs.getFirstName().compareTo(rhs.getFirstName());
       }
   });
   Queue<Passenger> waitingList = new LinkedList<>();

   Cruise cruise = new Cruise("1", passengerSet, waitingList, false);

   cruiseMap.put("1", cruise);
   Passenger passenger = new Passenger("Smith", "J");
   cruiseMap.get("1").getPassengerSet().add(passenger);
   ```
3. Implement the `Comparable<T>` interface in your `Passenger` class.

   ```
   public class Passenger implements Comparable<Passenger> {
       private String lastName = "";
       private String firstName = "";

       public Passenger()
       {
           lastName = "no last name yet";
           firstName = "no first name yet";
       }
       public Passenger(String lastName, String firstName)
       {
           this.lastName = lastName;
           this.firstName = firstName;
       }
       /**
        * @return the lastName
        */
       public String getLastName()
       {
           return lastName;
       }
       /**
        * @param lastName the lastName to set
        */
       public void setLastName(String lastName)
       {
       this.lastName = lastName;
       }
       /**
        * @return the firstName
        */
       public String getFirstName()
       {
           return firstName;
       }
       /**
        * @param firstName the firstName to set
        */
       public void setFirstName(String firstName)
       {
           this.firstName = firstName;
       }
       /* (non-Javadoc)
        * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
        */
       @Override
       public String toString()
       {
           return lastName + " " + firstName;
       }

       @Override
       public int compareTo(Passenger another) {
           return firstName.compareTo(another.firstName);
       }
   }
   ```